# Bookdown with pandoc-citeproc

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, bookdown, pandoc-citeproc

I have the latest version of bookdown package and Rstudio, and I'm on Arch Linux.

I updated pandoc-citeproc to its latest version and after that I started to receive the following error message:

```
pandoc: Error running filter /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc-citeproc
fd:5: hClose: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Regardless of the output type and even without references in the document, I get this error and the Rstudio preview is not generated. To view the generated document I have to open the index file in the browser and go giving F5 as I'm updating the document.

If I insert references the document is neither generated.

I searched in the AUR repository for other packages, uninstalled and re-installed pandoc-citeproc, but nothing solved.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe try installing with stack or cabal? http://pandoc.org/installing.html#compiling-from-source

Answer (score 0):

I run Arch as well, and I also encountered this issue after upgrading to `pandoc-citeproc-0.10.4.1-39`.

Temporarily solved by downgrading to `pandoc-citeproc-0.10.4.1-37`. Super easy to do, provided you still have the package cached on your system:

- `cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg`
- `sudo pacman -U pandoc-citeproc-0.10.4.1-37-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`